# Panel.Dock Fill ignoring other Panel.Dock setting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2005

If you create a panel on a form and set it to Dock=Top and drop another panel and set its Dock=Fill, it may fill the entire form, ignoring the first panel. Changing the tab order does nothing.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Docking layout depends on the **order** of sibling controls. Controls are docked "bottom up", so **the last control in the collection is docked first**. A docked control only take the layout of *previously* docked siblings into account. Hence the control with Dock=Fill should be first (top) in the sibling order, if you want it to take the other docked controls into account. If it is not the first control, earlier controls will overlap it.

This can be confusing because the sibling-order is not necessarily the same as the visual order, and the sibling order is not always apparent from the design view.

The **Document outline** window (View -> Other Windows -> Document outline) gives a useful tree-view over the control hierarchy and order, and allows you to change the sibling order of controls.

You can also change sibling order directly in the designer by context menu -> Bring to front / Send to back, which moves the control to be first or last of the siblings. These menu labels may be somewhat confusing since the actual effect depends on the layout model.

With fixed positioned controls, the 2D position is independent of the sibling order, but when controls are overlapping, the control earliest in the order will be "on top", hiding part of siblings later in the order. In this context Bring to front / Send to back makes sense.

Inside flow- or table-layout panels, the creation order determines the visual order of the controls. There is no overlapping controls. So bring to front/send to back really means make first or last in the order of controls.

With docked layout, the bring to front / send to back may be even more confusing since it determines in which order the docking is calculated, so "bring to front" on a fill-docked control will place the control in the *middle* of the parent, taking all edge-docked controls into account.

Comment: i have a panel, status strip, and menu strip all on a form and it seems that when i dock the menu strip to the top, the status strip to the bottom, and fill the panel, the panel doesnt fill the space in between the two strips unless it is the first sibling (at the top of the Document Outline window above the two strips). Moving the panel down (towards "last") covers over the strips.

So should the Dock=Fill control actually be the first sibling in the order? Am i reading this wrong?

i'm using 3.5 (2008). Did this change?

Comment: tl;dr; Right click on the panel with Dock=Fill and click 'Bring to Front'.

Comment: I have 3 groupboxes inside a panel and just like @Jugglingnutcase I had to have them ordered like: Dock.Fill, followed by Dock.Bottom, and finally Dock.Top, in order to have them 3 properly docked. In any case, awesome post!

Comment: +1 for Document Outline window. Never knew this existed, yet it's so useful.

Comment: How can I do this programatically? I mean, I'm adding the controls dynamically so I can't use the designer to do this.

Comment: @Camilo: If you add controls dynamically, you should add them in the order you want.

Comment: @JacquesB So besides adding them in the order I want, there's no way to have them re-order later, correct? Short of removing them all, and adding them again re-arranged.

Comment: I think you can reorder the control collection by removing controls and inserting again at specific indexes. But you should probably ask a separate question about this, since I'm not sure.

Comment: @JacquesB: I can confirm along with the other comments and answers that the solution is to put the Dock=Fill control *first* in the sibling order in the Document Outline, not last as described in the answer. Would you like to edit the answer to correct this? Or I would be happy to make the edit, but I don't want to be presumptuous. Thanks!

Comment: +1: I cannot believe how much time I lost trying to figure this out! Why the **** isn't this documented better?

Comment: I've been working with this sort of thing for a while now, and this is the first time I've seen the Document Outline mentioned or explained anywhere. Suddenly, a WHOLE LOT OF STUFF is starting to make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 123):

Right click on the panel with Dock=Fill and click 'Bring to Front'.

This makes this control be created last, which takes into account the Dock settings on other controls in the same container.

Comment: Simple, Godsend, this had really been annoying me

Comment: Makes sense once you think about it.

Answer (score 11):

I've had the same problem and I managed to solve it.
If you have a container with  `DockStyle.Fill` the others should also have DockStyle but Top or whatever you want.
The important thing is to add the control with  `DockStyle.Fill` first in Controls then the others.

Example:

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
cb.Dock =  DockStyle.Top;

GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.Dock =  DockStyle.Fill;

Controls.Add(gv); // this is okay
Controls.Add(cb);
```

but if we put cb first

```
Controls.Add(cb);
Controls.Add(gv); // gv will overlap the combo box.
```

Answer (score 7):

Another, potentially cleaner option is to use the TableLayout control. Set up one row of the desired height for your top dock, and another row to fill 100% for your bottom. Set both panels inside to Fill, and you're done.

(TableLayout does take some getting used to, though.)

Comment: TableLayout is also slower than docking conterols for layout performance, particularly if you have nested usercontrols which use TableLayout.  However, it does yield a nice layout to be sure.

Comment: Is this performance hit something an average user would see in a simple case of two panels, as described above? Or is it something they notice when you have dozens of UCs, all with layouts, all in one layout? (Ironically, the app I'm currently working on is like that, and performance seems OK ... )

Comment: TableLayout is pretty light-weight.  You won't see performance issues if you are just laying out a few controls.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the order of the elements inside the code, you can use the method Container.Controls.SetChildIndex() with Container being the e.g. Form, Panel etc. you want do add your controls to.

Example:

```
     //Container ------------------------------------
     Panel Container = new Panel();

     //Top-Docked Element ---------------------------
     ButtonArea = new FlowLayoutPanel();
     Container.Controls.Add(ButtonArea);
     Container.Controls.SetChildIndex(ButtonArea, 1);
     ButtonArea.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

     //Fill-Docked Element --------------------------
     box = new RichTextBox();
     Container.Controls.Add(box);
     Container.Controls.SetChildIndex(box, 0); //setting this to 0 does the trick
     box.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Answer (score 1):

JacquesB had the idea with the document outline but the hierarchy didn't solve my problem.
My controls were not in a hierarchical style they were just listed with the same parent.

I learned that if you changed the order it will fix the way you want it to look.

The controls on the bottom of the list will overlap the controls on top of it in the Document Outline window. In your case you would make sure that the first panel is below the second panel and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I discovered something useful.  To adjust sibling control order programatically for dynamically created control(s), you can do something like:

```
parentForm.Controls.SetChildIndex (myPanel, 0)
```

In my case, I did this to move a Dock/Fill panel to be the first control in my form so that it would not overlap with another docked control set to Dock/Top (a menu strip).

Comment: I had tried a few of these answers as I'm adding a control dynamically without success, and was considering adding a pre-docked panel as nothing else would work.Thankfully, I found this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick that worked for me..

Place the Top item and dock it top.

Place a Splitter, and also dock it top, then set it disabled (unless you want to resize the top).

Then Place the Fill object and set Docking to Fill.  The object will stay below the splitter.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  Mine was with adding new/custom controls below the menu strip during run time.  The problem was the controls when docked, decided to dock from the top of the form and completely ignoring the menu strip entirely, very annoying if you ask me.
As this had to be done dynamically with code and not during design mode this became extremely frustrating.  The simplest way I found is to create a panel during design mode and dock below the menu strip.  From there you can just add/remove the controls to the panel and you can dock it during run time.  No need to mess with all your controls on your form that do not really need to change, too much work depending on what you really need to do.

```
object.dock = Fill
Panel.Controls.Add(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also may be a fast solution to take the "Filled" component and right click, cut and paste in the desired area.