# Docking multiple controls - one fills remaining space

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to dock N number of controls in a container. I want them all to fill the entire width, but stack.  I want one particular control (currently the last one) to fill the remaining space, while all others have fixed sizes.

This:

```
Button b1 = new Button() { Text = "Button 1", Dock = DockStyle.Top };
Button b2 = new Button() { Text = "Button 2", Dock = DockStyle.Top };
Button b3 = new Button() { Text = "Button 3", Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

Controls.Add(b1);
Controls.Add(b2);
Controls.Add(b3);
```

Produces this:

[image: Button 3 filling entire parent]

As you can see, Button 3 is doing exactly what I told it to: `Fill` the parent.  But that's not what I *want* it to do.  Aside from manually placing, and handling resize events, etc. how can I make Button 3 fill the remaining space?

Note: I am *not* using the designer.

Comment: See [here][1]. This is a duplicate.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154543/panel-dock-fill-ignoring-other-panel-dock-setting

Answer (score 37, accepted):

While adding `b3.BringToFront()` (after it has been added to `Controls`) works, the simplest solution here, is to simply change the order in which the buttons are added to `Controls`.  The following code works perfectly:

```
Button b1 = new Button() { Text = "Button 1", Dock = DockStyle.Top };
Button b2 = new Button() { Text = "Button 2", Dock = DockStyle.Top };
Button b3 = new Button() { Text = "Button 3", Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

Controls.Add(b3);    // this guy first!
Controls.Add(b1);
Controls.Add(b2);
```

The result:

[image]

If you take a close look at the borders in this little example, this actually seems to work *better* than `BringToFront()`.

Comment: If you right on button3 and click "Brint to Front" it exactly does this for you.

Comment: That only works when you're using the designer, which in this case I am not.

Comment: Is there a way to put spacing in between the buttons? With padding/margins?

Comment: @ErikBerkun-Drevnig I think all paddings/margins will be denied, but you can do spacing by wrapping button by panel

Answer (score 6):

Basically the `DockStyle.Fill` control should be added first in the `Controls` collection.

Answer (score 5):

Use Bring to Front on your Button 3 in the designer, or call this code:

```
b3.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Z-order to me. I knew it affected the order in which they were docked (esp. for the `DockStyle.Top` ones) but I didn't think to move my `DockStyle.Fill control`. See my answer for a different take.

Comment: Yeah, that's the right answer. The Z-Order is important. You can also do this in the IDE. Also it is recommended to use panels for the layout.

Answer (score -1):

button 1 and 2 should have dock property set to top and to make button 3 take the rest of the space you can set its dock property to bottom.

dock = fill will make the button fill the entire space not just the remaining space. Bottom will function just as top did, but anchoring it to the bottom of the parent container. Apply buttons in order of 1, 2, 3.

Furthermore, you could set the dock property to top on all three and simply size button three differently.

Comment: WinForms doesn't have a stack panel.  Panel, FlowLayoutPanel and TableLayoutPanel are your choices.

Comment: Sorry, just came off WPF project lol. Edited to be correct. Wouldn't FlowLayoutPanel do the same thing? It flows, but with dock set to top the child control width would equal parent container width so they show flow correctly. Just trying to think outside the box a bit.