# Dock Panel on Button Click C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel, dock

I'm using WinForms. In my form i have 2 panels which i want to dock up or down on button click.

The issue i'm running into is that my panels is not docking correctly. 
When i click on the up button, panel one label gets covered by panel2.

Panel 1: (Anchor: Top, Left, Right)

Panel 2: (Anchor: Top, Bottom, Left, Right)

```
    private void Up_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

        panel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
    }

    private void Down_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

        panel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
    }
```

Incorrect the label should not be covered by the panels

[image]

What supposed to happen when Up button is clicked

[image]

What supposed to happen when Down button is clicked

[image]

Comment: Panel1 fills the entire form, Panel2 overlaps it.  Thus hiding the label. You'll have to rearrange the Z-order the controls, this.Controls.SetChildIndex() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    panel1.BringToFront();
}

private void Up_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
}

private void Down_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
}
```

The trick is to correct the order of the controls.

See here: [Docking multiple controls - one fills remaining space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749408/docking-multiple-controls-one-fills-remaining-space)